# Add more extensions to move different kind of files

Tags: batch

I have some files and some folders.
I use this script to move all `.pdf` files into folders.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do if exist "%%I*.pdf" move /Y "%%I*.pdf" "%%I\"
endlocal
```

But I want to move also `.rar`, `.cbr`, `.cbz` files. 
How can I do add these extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I do add these extensions?

This is one solution.

```
echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do (
  if exist "%%I*.pdf" move /Y "%%I*.pdf" "%%I\"
  if exist "%%I*.rar" move /Y "%%I*.rar" "%%I\"
  if exist "%%I*.cbr" move /Y "%%I*.cbr" "%%I\"
  if exist "%%I*.cbz" move /Y "%%I*.cbz" "%%I\"
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, it works

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `if exist` to your `move` command with `2>nul`

If the files exist, they will already be moved in a single command, if they do not exist, any error messages will be suppressed, and the potential error has no impact on files, it just appears on the screen.

For such a predictable error and without major impact, you can only suppress the messages.

It is the same treatment that you are using in the `dir` command inside your `for /f` loop **`dir / ... 2>nul`**

Use an additional `for` loop and add as many extensions as you need:

---

```batch-file
@echo off && setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F tokens^=* %%I in ('dir /A:D /B /O:-N 2^>nul')do for %%i in (
    rar,zip,cbr,cbz,pdf)do 2>nul move/Y ".\\%%~I*.%%~i" ".\\%%~I\."

endlocal
```

---

---

- Additional resources:

- [`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [`Move /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.